# momentjs get time difference

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs

I am trying to get the time that user spent in a page with moment.js but it returns the wrong value.

Code:

```
dateStart: any;

ngOnInit() {
  this.dateStart = moment(); // current time
}

// when user post data before being redirect
moment(moment(this.dateStart).diff(moment())).format("hh:mm:ss");
```

The code above supposed to return for instance `00:00:04` which means user was in this page for `4 seconds`. but I got something like this `06:59:55`

Any ideas?

Comment: I suspect you’re formatting a date that’s 4 seconds into january 1, 1970, adjusted for your time zone offset. You’re looking for an interval, not a date.

Comment: @rayhatfield what do you think I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want number of seconds(diff) why not use diff function of momentjs with measurements arguments( *supported ones are `years`, `months`, `weeks`, `days`, `hours`, `minutes`, and `seconds` default is miliseconds.*)

```
var a = moment([2007, 0, 29]);
var b = moment([2007, 0, 28]);
a.diff(b, 'days') // 1
```

```js
let dateStart = moment([2020, 9, 2, 12, 0, 0, 125]);


let futureTime = moment(); 

let secondsAgo = (futureTime.diff(dateStart, 'seconds') % 60);
let minutesAgo = (futureTime.diff(dateStart, 'minutes') % 60);
let hoursAgo = futureTime.diff(dateStart, 'hours');
console.log('hour: ' + hoursAgo + ', minute: ' + minutesAgo + ', seconds: ' + secondsAgo)
let hms = moment({
  hour: hoursAgo,
  minute: minutesAgo,
  seconds: secondsAgo
});
console.log(hms.format('HH:mm:ss'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i don't just want seconds, i want hours, minutes and seconds

Comment: I have updated the code to show the diff in HH:mm:ss format

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you’re formatting a date that’s 4 seconds into january 1, 1970, adjusted for your time zone offset. You’re looking for a [duration](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/), not a date.

Why format it at all? Why not just record the raw duration? You don’t need moment to subtract one time stamp
from another. Date.now() will get you the current timestamp:

```js
this.startDate = Date.now();

// ...a few moments later...

const duration = Date.now() - this.startDate; // number of ms between then and now
```

Comment: `1` If I use `moment.duration(this.dateStart)` it gives me `PT444891H22M42.093S` `2` `Why not just record the raw duration?` please show me how to? I am open to all solutions as long as they give me what I'm looking for

Comment: that returns `3848` idk what that means :D

Comment: That means 3848 milliseconds between start and end, or 3.848 seconds.

Comment: Of course. Divide by 1000 to get seconds, divide seconds by 60 to get minutes, etc., or use one of the many existing packages that do this, like [hh-mm-ss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hh-mm-ss).

Comment: couldn't do it :/

Answer (score 0):

You can try converting to UTC first.

```
moment.utc(moment().diff(this.dateStart)).format("HH:mm:ss.SSS"); //include milliseconds
```

```js
let start = moment();

setTimeout(() => {
  const duration = moment.utc(moment().diff(start));
  console.log(duration.format("HH:mm:ss.SSS"));
}, 1500);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: how can i change timezone from `utc`?

Comment: look at the code i just gave you, its a slight change to your code

Comment: I'd like your approach it's clean with minimum requirements of codes but i really don't want to use `utc()` is there any way that you can show my how to use my local instead of utc?

Comment: well it doesnt matter what you use. You are not referring to locale time, you just need it to be displayed in a readable form.

Answer (score 0):

There is no function in plotly.js which returns the difference as a new plotly object. I think the only way to do this is to get the time difference in seconds and then calculate the minutes and hours.

The following should work. It returns the time difference as `String`. So the seconds and minutes are always between 0 and 60 and the hours are greater than 0. A result of `74:12:40` would mean that the user stayed 74 hours, 12 minutes and 40 seconds on that page.

```
function runTest() {
    let startDate = moment('02.10.2020 8:00:00', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss');
    let endDate = moment('03.10.2020 10:24:38', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss');
    getDifferenceTime(startDate, endDate);
}


function getDifferenceTime(startDate, endDate) {
    // Get time difference in seconds
    let seconds = endDate.diff(startDate, 'seconds');
    let minutes = 0;
    let hours = 0;
    // Calculate number of minutes
    if (seconds >= 60) {
        minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
        seconds -= minutes * 60;
    }
    // Calculate number of hours
    if (minutes >= 60) {
        hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
        minutes -= hours * 60;
    }
    let timeString = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
    console.log(timeString);
    return timeString;
}
```

You can test it with the code snipped above. It should return `26:24:38`, which is your expected output.